# How do I test array element types using BDD Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd

I am writing a Javascript unit test using the BDD style. I want to test that a value

1. is an array
2. has all string elements

I can get the first condition with

```
value.should.be.an('array');
```

Is there a way to test for the second condition using this idiom?

Comment: what you use for that ? since it is not jasmine, you could easily iterate over the values of the array and test them for being a string with expect(typeof(elment)).toEqual("string")

Comment: You'd need a custom matcher or just iterate and test the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a clean way to do it would be to use Array.prototype.every, which would give you a boolean value indicating if every value in the array was a string. You can then use this value in your assertion.

```
value.every(function(el){ 
    return typeof(el) === 'string';
}).should.be.true;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about…

`var nonStrings = myArray.filter(function( val ){
  return val.be.a.String;
});`

nonStrings.should.be.empty;

Comment: No, because I just know it's supposed to be a list of strings. I don't know what the strings actually are.